# Uncaught Reference Error: module is not defined angular 7 while working app

Tags: angular

I have recently created an app with angular 7 frontend and c# backend and I get this error in console although the app works.

[Sources Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgP2H.jpg)

[Console Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7YqmM.jpg)

My tsconfig.json configuration is:

```
{ "compileOnSave": true, "compilerOptions": { "target": "es6", "module": "commonjs", "moduleResolution": "node", "sourceMap": true, "emitDecoratorMetadata": true, "experimentalDecorators": true, "removeComments": false, "noImplicitAny": false, "typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types" ], "types": [ "core-js" ] } }
```

This is the console error:

```
scripts.0854bee9c076f00a7812.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: module is not defined
    at scripts.0854bee9c076f00a7812.js:1
(anonymous) @ scripts.0854bee9c076f00a7812.js:1
```

and this is the part of code that indicates the error caught:

```
 module.exports = function(e, t, n) {
        if ("function" == typeof Array.prototype.findIndex)
            return e.findIndex(t, n);
        if ("function" != typeof t)
            throw new TypeError("predicate must be a function");
        var i = Object(e)
          , r = i.length;
        if (0 === r)
            return -1;
        for (var o = 0; o < r; o++)
            if (t.call(n, i[o], o, i))
                return o;
        return -1
    }
```

I hope that helped

Any ideas what might be wrong here and I am getting this error?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please paste the errors and not attached them as screenshots.

Comment: Receiving the same errors on an upgrade from 7 -> 8. Something odd is going on in the module resolution.\